# How to select correct element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created tables. And I would like to addClass in some range.

My desired result is like below,

[image]

In my work,some cells didn't work well, and I would like to fix it.

What is the wrong point? and How can I fix it ?

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    index = $("td").index(this);
    $("tr .color").slice(index + 1, index + 3).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('red');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your desired result when clicking which cell? And now you are making the clicked number background red too, that is not according to the desired image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want, but this matches your image

I commented out the clicked cell and removed the +1
I also removed the class before colouring

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    // $(this).toggleClass('red');
    $("tr .color").removeClass("red");
    index = $("td").index(this);
    $("tr .color").slice(index, index + 3).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('red');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```